# Proguard: IllegalArgumentException - Unexpected error while evaluating instruction

Tags: android, release, proguard, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to build a release apk with the proguard enabled. I'm getting the error below. I will attach the full stacktrace below.

```
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
Class       = [*]
  Method      = [myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V]
  Instruction = [532] aload_3 v3
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
  Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [*]
  Method      = [myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
:*:proguardRelease FAILED
```

I've narrowed the issue down to lines of code that is not mentioned in the stacktrace.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

If I am to comment this out, proguard finishes without problem.

I've currently upgraded the proguard to the new 5.0 and it had no effect.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Exception full stacktrace :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':*:proguardRelease'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue]
at proguard.evaluation.value.Value.referenceValue(Value.java:97)
at proguard.evaluation.Variables.aload(Variables.java:263)
at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitVariableInstruction(Processor.java:688)
at proguard.classfile.instruction.VariableInstruction.accept(VariableInstruction.java:306)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:753)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:602)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
at proguard.optimize.info.ParameterUsageMarker.visitCodeAttribute(ParameterUsageMarker.java:176)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
at proguard.optimize.info.ParameterUsageMarker.visitProgramMethod(ParameterUsageMarker.java:136)
at proguard.optimize.OptimizationInfoMemberFilter.visitProgramMethod(OptimizationInfoMemberFilter.java:81)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:394)
at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 47 more
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is probably a bug in ProGuard's optimization of enum types. You may be able to work around it by disabling this optimization:

```
-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum
```

If you can file a bug report or mail me details, I'll look into it.

(I am the developer of ProGuard)

Comment: @Eric, I'm hitting this with proguard 5.2 (even though I extracted a method as Calvin suggested).  Is there a bug report I can track for this?

Comment: @Eric, Could you please post more detailed reference of where to add `-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum`?

Answer (score 0):

Weird solution, but I've found a way to fix it. The exact section of the code that was causing the proguard issue was separated out into a different method and at the old location that method was called.  This seems to have fixed the problems, even though I'm not sure how it solved it. It just seems more and more like a Proguard bug. It works for me so that is something that others can try if they ever run into this issue.