# LEADBOLT ads proguard error line 1

Tags: android, leadbolt, android-proguard

i integrated LEADBOLT ads in my android application i use Proguard. When i export apk than following error occur.
I post here console error and Proguard-project.text

I include AdColony in my android app and now I am trying to export my app with proguard. I found configuration for AdColony here and here. I tried to include them separately and together into proguard.cfg, but it doesn't work.

Console Error

```
  [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   Class       = [com/apptracker/android/module/AppModuleLoader]
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   Method      = [onFailed(Lcom/apptracker/android/listener/AppModuleListener;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V]
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   Exception   = [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException] (-1)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.optimize.peephole.BranchTargetFinder.visitConstantInstruction(BranchTargetFinder.java:492)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.instruction.ConstantInstruction.accept(ConstantInstruction.java:157)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:138)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:110)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.optimize.peephole.BranchTargetFinder.visitCodeAttribute(BranchTargetFinder.java:354)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:261)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
    [2015-08-04 12:22:44 - Leadboat Demo]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Proguard File Code

```
enter code here

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontnote java.awt.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.**


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepnames class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput*
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {<init>(...);}
#GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {*;}
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {*;}

# AdColony
-dontwarn android.webkit.** 
-dontwarn com.jirbo.adcolony.**
-keep class com.jirbo.adcolony.**{*;}

-keep class com.apptracker.** { *; } 
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* { 
    public static <fields>; 
} 
-keep class **.R$*
```

Comment: do you have enums in your project..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368971/proguard-illegalargumentexception-unexpected-error-while-evaluating-instructi check this once

Comment: When we apk signed is error .. We have let proguard to use. Please help me.

Comment: i use in application LEADBOLT ads.

Comment: can you post your com/apptracker/android/module/AppModuleLoader class and com/apptracker/android/listener/AppModuleListener files for refernce

Comment: Define how the class and file is not in proguard of error.

Comment: am asking java class and interface what you are getting error.i.e AppModuleLoader and AppModuleListener

Comment: @RamBabuPudari :- Send your facebook Id i send you Java File