# How to configure proguard for Google Cloud Endpoint in android studio

Tags: android, proguard, google-cloud-endpoints, android-proguard

Trying to understand proguard (actually I just want it to work), I start with a very simple hello world app. So far so good. Then I add my google cloud endpoint. Nothing else. Once I add the endpoint, proguard throws an exception:

```
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient$1: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.RequestDirector
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.RequestLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.RequestLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void setContentEncoding(java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void setContentType(java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpVersion
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpVersion
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnPerRouteBean
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnPerRouteBean
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport$Builder: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport$Builder: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParams
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport$Builder: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport$Builder: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoutePlanner
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpRequestRetryHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.RedirectHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.AuthenticationHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.AuthenticationHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.UserTokenHandler
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.RequestDirector
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.api.client.testing.http.apache.MockHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy

...
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Exception while processing task 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So the only reason I am having a problem is because of the cloud endpoint, which [I add using android studio](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/add_module). So my question is **How do I configure a Google Cloud Android app for proguard?**

Because of the fail message from Proguard, I changed my `proguard-rules.pro` from having nothing to having the following:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
-keep class com.google.api.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.api.**
-keep class com.google.common.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-keep class com.mycompany.cloud.Cloud.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.cache.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.primitives.**
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
```

Now proguard crashes with a different message

```
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory$Feature]
  Method      = [collectDefaults()I]
  Instruction = [22] getfield #8
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "i" is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory$Feature]
  Method      = [collectDefaults()I]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "i" is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue])
Exception while processing task 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value "i" is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue]
    at proguard.evaluation.value.Value.referenceValue(Value.java:97)
    at proguard.evaluation.Stack.apop(Stack.java:330)
    at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.visitFieldrefConstant(BasicInvocationUnit.java:197)
    at proguard.classfile.constant.FieldrefConstant.accept(FieldrefConstant.java:69)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.constantPoolEntryAccept(ProgramClass.java:465)
    at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.invokeMember(BasicInvocationUnit.java:179)
    at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitConstantInstruction(Processor.java:591)
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.ConstantInstruction.accept(ConstantInstruction.java:157)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:761)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:609)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:567)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:271)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:188)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:81)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:92)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:73)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:516)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.ClassAccessFilter.visitProgramClass(ClassAccessFilter.java:67)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:358)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
    at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:462)
    at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:328)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:127)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**UPDATE** Gradle file:

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycomp.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 11
    versionName "0.0.11"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':myendpoint', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. So I am actually re-creating my app from scratch because the final version was not working with proguard. I don't want to `-dontwarn` a bunch of stuff and end up crashing my app in production, which is the problem I was having.

Comment: Are you able to share your project source? If you can't, just the Gradle files would be helpful, or the structure of your app, and where you've configured proguard.

Comment: I update with gradle file

Comment: I'm afraid I know absolutely nothing about Proguard. Could it be that you have a version conflict with your jackson version?

This error happens during proguarding? If you remove the cloud module dep does proguard work?

Comment: I had this error, try: -optimizations !class/unboxing/enum (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368971/proguard-illegalargumentexception-unexpected-error-while-evaluating-instructi)

Comment: Hello did it worked for you