# Failed to sign in Google Play Services when Proguard is applied

Tags: android, libgdx, proguard, google-play-games

My Android application is using Google Play Games Services and I use the module provided by google, **"BaseGameUtils"**.

The Application works perfect and I can Sign In when its build is on **debug**, but when I build it on **release** and applying proguard, it displays **"Failed to sign in"**.

Here is my Proguard:

```
-verbose
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes SourceFile
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends com.badlogic.gdx.Application
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote java.nio.file.Files, java.nio.file.Path
-dontnote **.ILicensingService
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4-25.0.1.jar
-libraryjars libs/google-play-games-10.0.1.jar
-libraryjars libs/google-play-games-25.0.1.jar


-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

Comment: You can do a Google search for what to add to your Proguard config file to make it work with GPGS.

Comment: This might be a bug due to "enum types". Can you try adding this line -optimizations !class/unboxing/enum ? This might be the same problem experienced in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368971/proguard-illegalargumentexception-unexpected-error-while-evaluating-instructi).